# Symbols allowed in digit only fields?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Im using the bassistance form validation. I have a couple of fields that require digits only, but that excludes symbols like $,(,),-,*, etc from being allowed and i need these for fields like prices and phone numbers. Anyone know a method or plugin or something to work around this?

**UPDATE**

Basically, i need a function that says "no text allowed" and allowed symbols and numbers.

**Another update**

Found a function that doesnt allow text alone. But if there are symbols, it allows text as well. Any way to restrict any text?

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
  "symbols",
  function(value,element){
    var hNum=/[^a-z\s-]/;
    var inp=jQuery.trim(element.value).toLowerCase();
    if(hNum.test(inp)) {    return true;
    }
    else return false;
    },
    "Number and symbols are only allowed."
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their documentation, there's already [validation methods](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods#List_of_built-in_Validation_methods) that can perform validation for: [decimal numbers](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/number), [digits](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/digits) and [phone numbers](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/phoneUS)

****EDIT**: In that case it sounds like you want to create a custom validation. There is a method called [addMethod](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage) which adds a custom validation with a call-back function like the one daGrevis created.

*Example:*

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("isdigit", function(value, element) {
        return /[\d()-.\$]/.test(value); 
    }, "Numbers and symbols only allowed"
);
```

Comment: none of those do what i need.. decimal numbers and digits dont allow $ signs, and phone numbers required a full number, whereas ill have phone extensions. (basically i need something that simply says no text allowed)

Comment: You don't get it or what?! You need to code that functionality! Check the value using my function (for example), if validation fails, somehow display it to end-user (`alert()` in the simplest case)! :/

Comment: I'm using the bassistance plug-in method to create a new method that can be attached to a field that will perform validation and display messages through the plug-in itself.

Comment: @daGrevis Ok almost there but this function doesnt allow $ - ( )

Comment: You need to pass string in it. Not jQuery object.

Comment: @daGrevis Oh that can be a problem because its implementing with a jquery plugin. is there javascript that can convert the object into a string?

Comment: Look at @CAbbott answers example.

Comment: @Jonah - I've modified my example to only allow for digits and the symbols "()-.$" It doesn't take order of them in to account though.

Comment: @CAbbott Appreciate it but its doing opposite, its allowing everything except digit and symbols "()-.$"

Comment: @Jonah - I notted the result. Wasn't sure the exact return value.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a little function for it...

```
function is_digit(value) {

    return String(value).search(/^\s*\d+\s*$/) != -1;

}
```

You can adapt it as you wish, of course. :)

**Edit:**

Here are other useful reg-exes:

- Is integer: `/^\s*(\+|-)?\d+\s*$/`?
- Is decimal-number: `/^\s*(\+|-)?((\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\.\d+))\s*$/`?

Comment: Great!! But where to i put this? In the actual validation script? On my own page?

Comment: Just check wanted value using that function... `is_digit(value)`. It will return boolean (`true`/`false`), so, with `if/else` construction, you can easily check that your value is or is not digit. Also, you can  check any of inputted chars in specified element and if that function returns `false`, just don't allow to add them in that `input`/`textarea`/whatever. P.S. Just don't forget to also check that on server-side! :)

Comment: Im sorry but im still a bit confused (not a jquery person) where do i insert this function (in the bassistance jquery script itself?) and where would i call it?

Comment: First, its not a jQuery. Its simple JavaScript. You don't need jQuery for all, its just a great library! Not a new programming language. :P You need to put this function somewhere before place where you will use it... and then? Use it!

Comment: Oh i see so its nothing to do with bassistance?

Comment: What the hell mean 'bassistance'?

Comment: @daGrevis - the OP is asking about adding custom validation through a jquery plugin: http://bassistance.de/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you might try a different approach to validation entirely.

My personal favorite is to use HTML5's validation and make all browsers jive/extend its functionality.

http://ericleads.com/h5validate/

Comment: I don't know why this was down-voted. HTML5 solutions should begin to be considered.

Comment: Thanks Joel.  Appreciate it.  I guess I'll take my way-of-the-future validation and go home.